# Creating new dataframes by selecting rows with numbers/digits

Tags: python, pandas

I have this small dataframe:

```
    index   words
0   home                # there is a blank in words
1   zone    developer zone
2   zero    zero
3   z3       z3
4   ytd2525 ytd2525
... ... ...
3887    18TH    18th
3888    180m    180m deal
3889    16th    16th
3890    150M    150m monthly
3891    10am    10am 20200716
```

I would like to extract all the words in `index` which contains numbers, in order to create a dataframe with only them, and another one where `words` containing numbers in both `index` and `words` are selected.
To select rows which contain numbers I have considered the following:

```
m1 = df['index'].apply(lambda x: not any(i.isnumeric() for i in x.split()))
m2 = df['index'].str.isalpha()
m3 = df['index'].apply(lambda x: not any(i.isdigit() for i in x))
m4 = ~df['index'].str.contains(r'[0-9]')
```

I do not know which one should be preferred (as they are redundant). But I would also consider another case, where both index and words contain numbers (digits), in order to select rows and create two dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question not clear. Happy to correct if I got the question wrong

For all words in `index` containing numbers  in their own dataframe please try:

```
df.loc[df['index'].str.contains('\d+'),'index'].to_frame()
```

and for words containing numbers in both `index` and `words`

```
df.loc[df['index'].str.contains('\d+'),:]
```

Comment: Was this helpful or you need more help?

Comment: Hi wwnde, sorry I missed the notification on your answer. Yes, it works great :) thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Happy to know it was of help